# NullPointerException when casting NodeList to Element

Tags: java, xml, dom, nullpointerexception

I am having some weird issues with my DOM-related code. Here it is:

```
public Item getItem(String id) throws ConstructorNotDefinedException {

    //Find the specific item Element we are working with
    Element item = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.items.getLength(); i++) { //items is a NodeList of all items, derived from the document Element

        Element currentItem = (Element) this.items.item(i);

        if (currentItem.getAttribute("id") == id) { //only runs once since every ID is unique

            item = currentItem;

        }

    }

    //The line with the error
    Element typeElement = (Element) item.getElementsByTagName("type").item(0);


    //more code using typeElement...
```

Here is the main class running the code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConstructorNotDefinedException {

        ItemDataReader reader = ItemDataReader.newInstance(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents", "path", "to", "xml", "document.xml"));

        Item testItem = reader.getItem("dog");

    }

}
```

The first part seems to work fine, no errors at all, but as soon as I try to get typeElement it throws a NullPointerException. None of the methods called in that line throw the exception so I don't know where it's coming from.

Here's a sample of the XML document I'm using:

```
<item id="dog">
    <type>1</type>
    <name>Dog</name>
    <strength>10</strength>
</item>
<item id="cat">
    <type>1</type>
    <name>Cat</name>
    <strength>10</strength>
</item>
```

I've tried a lot of things, and I just don't know what is going on. Help is very much appreciated!

EDIT:

I tried the suggestions from Benjamin W. and using `.equals()` seems to have fixed the problem. I'm still not quite sure why using `==` was not working.

Comment: Your `item` is probably null. It is never set in the for loop if the condition is never satisfied.

Comment: You should also use `.equals()` not `==`. By all means add print statements to see. You need to have a solution if none of them equal that `id` cause it will be null

Answer (score 0):

After researching the difference, it seems that using `.equals()` has made the code compare the content of the Strings, rather than compare the references, like `==` did. Since the references would always be different, it was returning false every time, and then trying to get some info from a null Object.